# Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.k@... - PayPal-Android-SDK 2.13.3

Tags: android, paypal, sslsocketfactory, trustmanager

I recently updated my Song Scrapbook app to the latest version and also made sure to update all third-party APIs used by the app. One such third-party tool is the PayPal Android SDK which I use to monetize my app since I live in a country where the Google Wallet Merchant service is currently not supported - which means I cannot use the Play Store in-app or once-off purchase systems in my app.

However, after updating the PayPal SDK to the latest version in my app (via mavenCentral) I get the following error in Android Studio (version: 1.5.1) everytime I want to execute a PayPal transaction:

```
    debug W/paypal.sdk: PayPalService created. API:19 PayPalSDK/PayPal-Android-SDK 2.13.3 (Android 4.4.4; samsung GT-I9060I; )
    03-20 16:58:45.540 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
    03-20 16:58:45.550 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
    03-20 16:58:45.550 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.paypal.android.sdk.at.a
    03-20 16:58:45.550 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 10405: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
    03-20 16:58:45.610 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug I/dalvikvm: Could not find method io.card.payment.CardIOActivity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method io.card.payment.CardIOActivity.onCreate
    03-20 16:58:45.610 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13172: Lio/card/payment/CardIOActivity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
    03-20 16:58:45.820 7804-7843/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug I/System: Loaded time zone names for "en" in 132ms (127ms in ICU)
    03-20 16:58:45.840 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4168cbc0)
    03-20 16:58:45.840 7804-7804/com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug, PID: 7804
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService@41e9c5a0 with Intent { cmp=com.whitsoft.songscrapbook.debug/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.k@41ff61a0, sslSocketFactory is class com.paypal.android.sdk.bn
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2987)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.k@41ff61a0, sslSocketFactory is class com.paypal.android.sdk.bn
                                                                                at a.ak.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at a.ak.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at a.am.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.paypal.android.sdk.bt.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2970)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     03-20 17:03:46.103 7804-7804/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7804 SIG: 9
```

I know this problem is not caused by the device on which I tested the app - as I have tested this app on two very different devices (Samsung Grand Neo and Cubot X15) and both devices produced similar errors. I tried googling the problem to try and solve the problem but after hours of searching found no solution.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.
SilSur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it took me roughly 5 hours to figure this one out - which I achieved through a  step-by-step elimination of possible causes of the problem.

Turns out the real problem was my haste in trying to update the app. The reason being that the PayPal SDK 2.13.3 version has a new rule in the 'proguard-rules.pro' file that is very important to include:

Rule as follows:

```
    # This is added for okhttp 3.1.2 bug fix as shown at https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2323
    -keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
         private javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
    }
```

This prevents the minify (obfuscation) process of Gradle from removing IMPORTANT code from a previous bug-fix in the PayPal SDK that caused problems with the secure layer socket factory. So yeah - that was the fix: the updated app now works perfectly (just as required).

Lesson learnt: make sure your 'proguard-rules' are exactly as they are suppose to be!

Over & Out, SilSur.

Comment: I had the same problem using JudoPay sdk - this was what fixed it. Thanks chum :)